# Get MD5 hash in a specifc format

Tags: typescript, md5, cryptojs

I have a db with passwords MD5 in the pattern `$2y$10$D46nsM/fVrTYDOR7BYjcOeoTtPS1p6J2ImrbwLh5x2Y1bV6.jsVZe` using crypto-js.

But in my typeScript project the `function CryptoJS.MD5("password")` is generating a array, when i do this `array.toString()` the value returned is `5b5523d720dea93549fe2a3c415891d3`. How can i return this array in the first pattern?

Comment: Could you please include code in the form of a [mcve]?

Comment: As a side note, you should absolutely not treat MD5 as cryptographically secure and suitable for sorting passwords. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

Comment: Im just doing "npm install crypto-js" and calling in a click of a button the function:                             Login(){ console.log( CryptoJS.M5("test").toString() )

Comment: Why do you believe this is MD5? `$2y$` passwords are crypt_blowfish. For documentation on the modular crypt format, see https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modular_crypt_format.html

Comment: Because in a previous project in php, i used CryptoJS.MD5("password") to generate the passwords.

Comment: Algorithm identifier `2y` is Blowfish, more specifically, Blowfish as generated by the `crypt_blowfish` PHP function after June 2011.